# How to find service name

Tags: c#, .net

Can some one help me how to find service name from task manager using the process id in c#. I have searched in the online. But, I couldn't find correct solution.

Comment: `var process = Process.GetProcessById(processId); string name = process.ProcessName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WMI to query the `Win32_Service` class.

```
var processId = 2220;

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
     $"SELECT * FROM Win32_service WHERE ProcessId={processId}");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
    var serviceName = queryObj["Name"]; // Access service name  
}
```